# Problemas com Js no WordPress, impedindo funcionamento de alguns plugins

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-mobile

estou iniciando uns trabalhos com WordPress e sou extremamente novato na área. Estou usando um plugin para o menu Max Mega Menu só que ele não está funcionando no mobile (aparece o menu mas quando apertou para abrir não tem nenhuma ação), estive procurando no fórum do plugin e reparei que 90% dos casos foram erros em js pelo site que impossibilitaram o plugin funcionar.
Consegui corrigir alguns, mas esse em questão não faço a mínima ideia de como resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.
Agradeço desde já

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Antes de fazer uma pergunta, talver seja melhor você ver [ask] e [mcve].

Comment: Olá Luiz, edite a pergunta e insira a mensagem de erro que aparece no console.

Comment: Esses são os erros que aparecem no console